# Как разбить сложную строку на массив?

Tags: php

Нужно распилить строку на массив.
Строка:

```
routes[0][1].action.controller[0].class
```

Массив:

```
array(
    [0]=> string(6) "routes",
    [1]=> string(3) "[0]",
    [2]=> string(3) "[1]",
    [3]=> string(6) "action",
    [4]=> string(10) "controller",
    [5]=> string(3) "[0]",
    [6]=> string(5) "class"
)
```

А еще лучше на:

```
array(
    [0]=> string(6) "routes",
    [1]=> int(0),
    [2]=> int(1),
    [3]=> string(6) "action",
    [4]=> string(10) "controller",
    [5]=> int(0),
    [6]=> string(5) "class"
)
```

Вот мой код

```
preg_match_all(
    '/([a-z0-9_]+)(\[\d+\])*(\.|$)/', 
    'routes[0][0].action.controller[0].class', 
    $matches
);
```

Но я получаю

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'routes[0][1]',
    1 => 'action',
    2 => 'controller[0]',
    3 => 'class',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'routes',
    1 => 'action',
    2 => 'controller',
    3 => 'class',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '[1]',
    1 => '',
    2 => '[0]',
    3 => '',
  ),
)
```

Comment: `preg_match_all(
    '/[a-z0-9_]+', 
    'routes[0][1].action.controller[0].class', 
    $matches
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищем слово или цифры в квадратных скобках

```
\w+|\[\d+\]
```

[**демо на regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/h8zzLb/1)

[**демо на eval.in**](https://eval.in/931116)

А чтобы получить цифры без скобок

```
\w+|(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])\]
```

[**демо на eval.in**](https://eval.in/931126)

Comment: @ИванАнтонов обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, мне как раз первый вариант нужен был `\w+|\[\d+\]`

Comment: Отлично, но пусть и второй полежит для кого-нибудь :) Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'routes[0][0].action.controller[0].class';

preg_match_all('/[a-z0-9]+|\[\d\]/', $string, $matches);
```

[пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2c6106a89f8f283a642529af91f53596cf72591)

Comment: В массиве значения в скобочках должны остаться без изменений т.е. в скобочках ЛИБО значение преобразовано к integer

Comment: @Иван Антонов обновил ответ